como sumar un rango de meses por medio de fechas en dataadd?
Holas, quisiera poder sacar la diferencia y que me saque los valores sumados
asi esta la tabla

quiero usar una consulta parecida
SELECT CIC,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Mes BETWEEN ,Mes DATEADD( MM,  -6, Mes) AND  Mes) THEN saldo END) AS [6Meses]      
FROM cart

quisiera poder agrupar 6 meses y que se muestre la SUM de los 6 meses que estan marcado con azul y de todas las fechas en si
Edito para que se entienda mejor ..los 6 registros es un ejemplo, el dateadd descuenta 6 meses, y quisiera una suma de esos datos ...bien podría tener 3 o 12 meses el dataadd y ese sería el rango para hacer un SuM esto necesito de cada mes o en este caso de cada fila

El problema es que no estás especificando cómo seleccionar esos registros. Estás marcando 6 registros en azul con meses (6, 5, 4, 3, 11 y 10), pero en el resto (los no marcados en azul) también tienes un mes 6, un mes 5,...  Si sólo quieres sumar esos 6 registros DEBE haber otra forma de diferenciarlos del resto.

Los primeros 6 registros o agrupar cada 6 registros?

@Yussef en si es agrupar de acuerdo a la diferencia de dateadd que en este caso es 6....bien podría ser 3

@GermánEstévez-Neftalí- marque 6 registros como ejemplo el dateadd está menos 6 meses ...por eso está marcado ...lo que quiero es que de cada mes ..osea que cada fila ...haga una suma de acuerdo a lo que ordena el dataadd

O sea.. agarras un registro.. haces una funcion ventana para sumar los 6 meses anteriores.. y luego que?? lo mismo para cada registro???

tambien se puede hacer mucho mas rapido con un procedimiento, porque otra vez lo que pedis no tiene mucho sentido.. tal vez, si nos explicas el problema real, podamos decirte como solucionarlo...

@gbianchi si lo mismo para cada registro..

Por favor no uses imágenes. Usa texto formateado en vez. Y danos un ejemplo con bastantes filas (unas veinte filas quizá) y el resultado corrspondiente. Así vamos a entender mejor lo que quieres hacer.

Esto es mi segundo intento de interpretar tu pregunta. Quizás es que quieres una extra columna que te da la suma de las seis meses hasta el mes de la fila. Para esto nesecitamos SUM(saldo) OVER (...) con una ventana (window).
Esto te da la suma de seis filas para cada fila en tu tabla:
SELECT
  mytable.*,
  SUM(saldo) OVER(PARTITION BY cic
                  ORDER BY mes
                  ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS saldo_de_seis_meses
FROM mytable
ORDER BY cic, mes;

Si esto no es exactamente lo que quieres, pero es más cerca que la otra respuesta, puedes leer más sobre ventanas en SQL aquí: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-window-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Tu ejemplo muestra que no hablas de meses consecutivos, sino de los meses que están en tu tabla. El mes más nuevo en tu tabla es 2022-06, y no buscas las seis meses 2022-01 hasta 2022-06, sino las meses más nuevos, que son seis meses entre 2020-10 y 2022-06. Entonces los seis meses segundo más nuevos, etc.
Por eso no puede funcionar DATEADD( MM,  -6, Mes). En vez buscamos grupos de seis filas. Para esto usamos ROW_NUMBER. Así recibimos filas con los números 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ... Si restamos 1 y dividimos con 6 sin resto, recibimos 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, ... que será nuestra llave para el GROUP BY.
with
  grupos as
  (
    select t.*, (row_number() over (order by mes desc) - 1) / 6 as grp
    from mytable t
  )
select
  grp + 1 as grupo,
  min(mes) as primer_mes,
  max(mes) as ultimo_mes,
  sum(saldo) as saldo_total
from grupos
group by grp
order by grp;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/MIURH67r

muy buena idea!!!! pero para mi, habria que ordenar la tabla de entrada tambien por fecha descendiente.. si no son 6 cualquiera...

@gbianchi: Gracias. No entiendo "ordenar la tabla de entrada tambien por fecha". Solamente podemos ordenar un resultado, y el resultado de esta consulta es una agregación. Entonces, como y donde ordenar la tabla de entrada?

perdon, tenes razon, el over esta ordenado... te recomendaria que expliques toda la sentencia, ya que por ejemplo alguien que no sepa como usar with u over, no va a entender nada de lo que hiciste... es mas.. por lo que vos mostrar, como volveria a refernciar el resultado con el original??? ojo con eso..

@gbianchi: Pues, esto es sintaxis nada más. Claro que puedo explicar como funciona WITH (...) AS y ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...) pero entonces todavía tenía que esplicar como funciona GROUP BY y quizás aún más. He añadido una demostración que también contiene una consulta que muestra ROW_NUMBER y la division.

Tampoco tan abajo.. pero decir porque agregas un with con un link a la documentacion, y porque el over es asi con otro link ayudan a quien no sepa que es, a seguir viendolo por si mismo... y si.. siempre tenes que pensar que quien pregunta no sabe mucho, o por lo menos intuirlo segun la pregunta...

@ThorstenKettner voy a revisar el código..pero solo tengo unas observaciones..de por sí lo que muestro en la captura ya tiene un row_number, lo use para enumerar los CIC (DNI) y lo ordene de el último mes que tenga registrado..(hay registro mas nuevos otros antiguos como 202202) y ese es el resultado de mi captura...ahora lo que busco es un decremento mensual...por decirse los 6 meses como aclaré es un ejemplo, ya que necesito hacer un SuM de 24 meses, 12,6 meses etc...de cads registro, es decir si estoy en 202402 me haga un cálculo 24 meses atras y que me haga un SuM de todos esos saldos,...

@ThorstenKettner lo mismo aplicaría para el siguiente registro 202401 ...hacer 24 meses atrás y sacar una sum de saldos ...y hacer eso en cada fila....en otro lado me siguieron crear una tabla temporal con fechas que me resten el campo mes aplicando el dateadd como -24 meses,12 etc ...pero el problema es que no se cómo podría cruzarla..eh intentado usar left join pero no me ha funcionado

No estoy seguro si entiendo. A ver ... La tabla que muestras ya es un resultado. Y no quieres agregar ese resultado más, sino quedarte con esas filas. Pero quieres añadir columnas, por ejemplo, una columna para 12 meses que contiene la sumación de los saldos de los 12 meses hasta el mes de la fila. ¿Si?

@ThorstenKettner podría modificar el resultado que ya tengo...pero solamente lo hice para que me mostrará de cada CIC todos sus meses de mayor a menor (o del más actual al más antiguo) y si en otra columna mostrar la suma de meses ..y con la siguiente fila hacer lo mismo.. lo siento por no ser más claro, quisiera mostrar más pero en mi trabajo me limitan el acceso a internet y todo lo hago desde el celular

A decir la verdad, no entiendo bastante. Lo siento. Puede ser, que no basta mi español. He escrito otra respuesta. Quizás sea más cerca a lo que quieres. Si todavía no es lo que necesitas, tienes que editar tu pregunta. En casa, si no es posible de tu trabajo.

@ThorstenKettner muchas gracias es exactamente lo que busco acabo de hacer la prueba y funciona como quiero...pero tengo algunas dudas ...esto en términos de eficiencia está bien? Me refiero a que me habían recomendado usar case when para que sea más "eficiente"..ahora tengo otra consulta, aparta de la suma, necesito sacar mín, max y avg, será posible con el código que me pasaste ? Y si quiero filtrar por 24 meses, 12 meses y 6 meses tendré algún problema? ..el código funciona perfecto es la lógica que busco pero quiero ver si es la más adecuada

Agregación condicional (CASE WHEN en una función de agregación) y ventanas (... OVER (...)) tienen una idea en común: Leemos la tabla solamente una vez para aumentar eficiencia. Hay casos en los cuales hay que usar agregación condicional, casos en los cuales hay que usar ventanas, y a veces las combinamos. No te preocupes de eficiencia. Es verdad, la tarea no es simple, entonces la consulta no es simple tampoco, pero es muy adecuado y probablemente lo más rápido posible.
